# How does a gradient descent algorithm work when it is already in a local minimum

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, minimization

In the context of gradient `descent algorithms`, (not linear regression), if the cost function is already at a local minimum, what happens next? or how does it reach the global optimum later on?

> In the case of linear regression there is only one minimum, and hence
>   no problem of a local minimum. But what about other algorithms that
>   might have a local minimum and a global minimum?